# First isomorphism Theorem and Cosets of K

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $\alpha:G \rightarrow G_1 $ be a group homomorphism with ker $\alpha$ = K. For $a \in G$ show that Ka = {$g \in G$|$\alpha(g) = \alpha(a)$}. I am studying the first isomorphism chapter of my book and I am confused what this question is asking. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking you to show that the coset $Ka$ consists of all elements $g$ which have the same image of $a$ under $\alpha$.

Sketch:

- Show that for every $g\in Ka$, $\alpha(g)=\alpha(a)$.  Since $g\in Ka$, $g=ka$ for some $k\in K$.  Now, compute $\alpha(g)$.
- Show that if $\alpha(g)=\alpha(a)$, then $g\in Ka$.  Since $g=(ga^{-1})a$, compute $\alpha(ga^{-1})$ to show that $ga^{-1}\in K$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So...

Suppose $g \in Ka$ then $g = ka$ for some $k \in K$ then $\alpha(g) = \alpha(ka) = \alpha(k)*\alpha(a) = 1_{G_1} *\alpha(a) = \alpha(a)$

Now suppose that $\alpha(g) = \alpha(a)$ then $\alpha(g)*\alpha(a)^{-1}$ = 
$\alpha(g)*\alpha(a^{-1})$ = $\alpha(ga^{-1})) = 1_{G_1}$ thus $ga^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $\alpha$ and so $ga^{-1}a \in Ka$ but $ga^{-1}a $ = g therefore $g \in Ka$, as required?

Comment: @Michael Burr is this correct? I am just trying to check and see if I understand properly...

Comment: James, sorry, I didn't get a notification for this comment.  This looks good to me.